# angular: Resetting ng-switch on dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This seems like such a mundane task, but i can't seem to reset the dropdowns to the original state. I'm using ng-switch for each value from the dropdown. I have researched this and I can't seem to find any documentation pertaining to my problem. There are similar questions that have been answered, and I have looked at the angularAPI, but none seem to fix my problem.

```
HTML:

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app = ""> <!--using the body to initialize the application-->
<p>Survey Form</p>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
      <p>
        <label>Email:
          <input type="text" name="cust_email" id="cust_email">
        </label>
      </p>
      <p>Please rate the following times from best (1) to worst (4)</p>

      <div ng-app = "myForm" ngController = "formControl">
      <p>
            <select id="option1" ng-hide = "time1" ng-model = "time1" value = "option1">
                <option value="1">1. Best time</option>
                <option value="2">2. Next Best time</option>
                <option value="3">3. Not as good</option>
                <option value="4">4. Worst time</option>
            </select>      
            Monday/Wednesday 10:10am-Noon
      </p>


      <div ng-switch = "time1" name = "switch1"><!--time1 module is reserved for Monday/Wednesday 10:10am-Noon dropdown-->
        <div ng-switch-when = "1"><!--when value 1 from the dropdown is selected-->
            <h3>This time is the: Best Time.</h3><hr><!--display this-->
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch = "time1">
        <div ng-switch-when = "2">
            <h3>This time is the: Next Best Time.</h3><hr>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch = "time1">
        <div ng-switch-when = "3">
            <h3>This time is the: Not as good.</h3><hr>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ng-switch = "time1">
        <div ng-switch-when = "4">
            <h3>This time is the: Worst Time.</h3><hr>
        </div>
      </div>
<p>
        <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit">
        <input type="reset" name="button2" id="button2" value="Reset" ng-click = "reset()">
      </p>


      </div>

angular:

<script>
    angular.module('myForm', []).controller('formControl', function ($scope){
        $scope.reset = function(){
            $scope.form1 = {};
        };
        });

      </script>

  </fieldset>  
</form>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever a value is selected from the dropdown, the ng-switch activates. This places text and removes the dropdown. Upon reset, the dropdown should reappear and the ng-switch text should disappear. Basically resetting everything to its original state.

I'm a little apprehensive to post any questions because any time I do I get down voted and scolded. I hope that this question is specific enough to help.

Comment: This question is good just be sure to include a minimal reproduction like you did here (ideally a link to jsfiddle plnkr or codepen makes it easier for those who want to help).  Don't take advice on SO too personally typically just volunteers like me who get frustrated with unclear questions or questions that show little research or effort.

Comment: @shaunhusain, Thank you for that input. I feel a little better:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple issues with your code.

First thing is that you don't need to define a new `ng-switch` for every case. `ng-switch` works like a switch statement, so you only need one `ng-switch` with each of the `ng-switch-when` divs inside. Like so:

```
  <div ng-switch="time1">
    <div ng-switch-when="1"><!--when value 1 from the dropdown is selected-->
      <h3>This time is the: Best Time.</h3><hr><!--display this-->
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="2">
      <h3>This time is the: Next Best Time.</h3><hr>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="3">
      <h3>This time is the: Not as good.</h3><hr>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="4">
      <h3>This time is the: Worst Time.</h3><hr>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Second, your `ng-hide` logic is a bit flawed for the dropdown select. You are setting `form1` to an empty object in your reset function, but the select's `ng-hide` is hiding based on `time1` being set. If you want to hide the dropdown when `time1` is set, you need to be setting `time1` to null to show it again, like so:

```
$scope.time1 = null;
```

See the attached plunkr for an example that does what (I think) you are trying to do.

https://plnkr.co/edit/kWxysaCoRcK1XP7XNczL

Comment: That worked marvelously! Thank you for your help. I can see how the function calls the name of the switch(time1, which is what is active after the selection has been made), and makes time1 null. Effectively  putting everything back to its original state. Like you said :)

Comment: You're welcome :). Please mark as correct answer if you don't mind!

Comment: Done! I actually have four drop downs on this form. I was able to get them all to work by using $scope.time1-time4 respectively as such:   var app = angular.module('myForm', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.time1 = null;
 $scope.time2 = null;
 $scope.time3 = null;
 $scope.time4 = null;
  };
});    I had changed a couple things to suit my form such as using 'myForm' as the module name rather than using the 'plunkr' name. Again, thank you for the help.